# UIView within UIScrollView keeps setting its width and height to 0

Tags: ios, xcode

My directory structure is this:

```
UIView
   UIScrollView
         UIView
              Label
              Label
```

I want to be able to center the uiView (the second one) to adjust its width for iphone 6. I set the uiscrollview width and height to constraint with 0 on all sides. Then when i set UIView constraints to all 0, which makes the uiview disappear. I don't know why it's disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout with scrollView, you have some options.
First, you can set width and height constraint to contentView, so scrollView gets it as a contentSize. Second (in addition to first), you can fill the scrollView of views with size constraints. Third, you can set contentSize manually. Forth, you can make outlets for contentView size constraint and set them in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` manually.

So, your view dissappear because contentSize of scrollView is zero.